# How to resolve path to scripts folder?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net application with an HTML page. I'm not using MVC. In this page I have:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>
```

When testing locally with IIS Express, the script is found because the full uri is `http://localhost`.

However, when deploying to IIS on a server, the uri is `http://myserver/myapp`. Thus, the scripts are not found, because the page tries to load them from `http://myserver` directly.

I've tried the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>
```

I've also added the `base` tag to the page, but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the page to point to the right folders?

Comment: you should provide the path relative to the root directory. try /myapp/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js

Comment: @Manish This is the only way that works when running in IIS. However, for running locally, this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use ResolveUrl in this way.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery- 3.1.0.min.js") %>" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  '..' inplace of tild sign as

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Scripts folder is in the same directory level as your HTML page, you could just omit the first / and it should work:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```